# Are there any full-featured tutorials or examples for faye on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, faye

I have worked with faye on node before, but now want to add it to a rails app. I've found plenty of quick integration guides and have it up and running, but my current implementation is pretty hacky. I've been unable to find any longer tutorials or examples including a good convention for the server to subscribe to the faye channels, interact with the rails models, and publish responses. Does anyone know of good resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the **[How to Use Faye as a Real-Time Push Server in Rails](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails/)** tutorial to be a good start:

> We’re going build a simple chat service. Now, Ryan Bates covered this on [Railscast #260](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye), however, we’re going to take a slightly different approach in this tutorial. First, we’ll create a chat service where users enter a public room, and everyone can chat with each other publicly. The second functionality we’ll be adding is private messages. Additionally, we’ll integrate some security to our implementation using Ryan Bate’s [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) gem.

In about one hour you get a hands-on experience and understanding of Faye, both as a server and as a client. By the end of it you have a very basic chat; and not only that, your chat is also secure via [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub).

Comment: this answer is right, but i wouldn't recommend using it now, it's out dated. the railscasts answer (chapter 260) is still valid

Comment: True, this tutorial's boot method is not compatible with the latest version of rails.  See my answer with up-to-date resources including a working example that is deployed to heroku.

Comment: private_pub is not workable with rails 4.2 and rails 5. I did not try other versions of rails. Its outdated

Answer (score 5):

The below links can be useful for you,

http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye?view=asciicast

First one exhibits the simple instant message application in Rails with the help of faye.

Answer (score 0):

Faye has moved towards rack compatibility, so using a config.ru file and booting with the command `rackup` is advised (the listen method will not work on the latest version of faye).

Booting Faye with rails isn't encouraged, because FAYE isn't compatible with development middleware in rails, meaning you will always need to run in production mode.

A minimalistic [barebones example](https://github.com/TheNotary/faye_rails_example) project was written, which deploys cleanly to heroku as observed live at [faye-rails-example.herokuapp.com](https://faye-rails-example.herokuapp.com/).